# Настройка репостов с сайта в соц сети

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, opengraph

Каким образом можно настроить картинку для репоста в соц сеть? Нужно сделать так что бы все репосты имели одну и ту же картинку, отличную от логотипа, и не являющуюся обложкой статьи. Пытался поменять через OG:image, но как то не работает. Мб что то с кодом не так?

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/repost.jpg" >
```

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-in-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте доступна ли картинка в content. Попробуйте прописать прямой путь к картинке. Я иногда использую плагин "Facebook Open Graph, Google+ and Twitter Card Tags", подходит и для vk